# ERC plugin for 32dbg debugger doesn't work

Tags: debugging, buffer-overflow

I'm using ERC.dbg plugin in x32dbg, the problem is the commands doesn't work, for example if I tried to type `ERC --Bytearray` as it appears in the help menue (see the picture), it doesn't work it display the help menue again.
[image]